# How do I declare a variable that's accessible from everywhere in my Rails application?

Tags: variables, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, global-variables

Just wondering how would one do to have something like devise has with current_user, a globally available variable in what I'm guessing is a session ?

By this I mean, to get anything in a view from somewhere else, you need the @ prefix

What is then this kind of variable ? How make such a variable available 'globally" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> something like devise has with current_user, a globally available variable in what I'm guessing is a session

`current_user` is not a global variable. For example, you can't reference `current_user` during application boot -- not only would that not make any sense, that also proves it isn't global since it's not available. Another quick way to tell if a variable is global in Ruby is that global variables start with a `$`.

Instead, `current_user` is a helper method that gets included into [ApplicationController](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) by [DeviseController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/42c35236326a218e37d2a9ff2ab69c4bd93371fe/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L56).

To make a similar method, you can add your own methods to your own app's `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_balance
  current_user.balance
end
```

However, be advised that if you find yourself putting more than a few truly application-wide helper methods in `ApplicationController`, you're almost certainly creating technical debt by mixing unrelated concerns together into your controllers.

Comment: Pfff... couldn't think about the helper. Thanks for pointing this out and for the edit, the question look smarter (;